# How to log a specific query?

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to log a specific query?

I have some matches in a game that quits unexpected. And the only way a match can quit is if an UPDATE query set the value of "matchStatus" to 2 in a row. Is it possible to log all the queries that do this? In that case, how do you do it?

e.g

```
$query = "UPDATE active_matches SET matchStatus = '2' WHERE match_id='$match_id'";
```

Thanks

Comment: You want make some file where all your queries are?

Comment: Yes, but not via any pre-made mysql/php mechanisms - wrap your `$query = ...` line with an `if($matchStatus = 2) { log query }` type construct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative solution, which is a little more complicated to implement, but may or may not be more suited to your needs, is to create a log table into which a trigger inserts entries upon the execution of such update queries:

```
CREATE TABLE AugitLog (
  `Timestamp`  TIMESTAMP,
  `User`       VARCHAR(16),
  `Host`       VARCHAR(255),
  `MatchID`    INT
);

DELIMITER ;;

CREATE TRIGGER audit_match_termination AFTER UPDATE ON active_matches FOR EACH ROW
IF OLD.matchStatus <> 2 AND NEW.matchStatus = 2 THEN
  INSERT INTO AuditLog VALUES (
    NOW(),                          -- timestamp
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(USER(),'@', 1), -- username
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(USER(),'@',-1), -- hostname
    NEW.match_id                    -- the match that was terminated
  );
END IF;;

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside your `my.conf` file add the line

`log = /var/log/mysql/someLog.log`

Restart mysqld and you'll have logs of these queries put here.

Later you can simply grep values out of the log file as per your needs:

`grep 'UPDATE active_matches' someLog.log` Matches all lines with *UPDATE active_matches*, and outputs, and obviously you can change the pattern if you want to check for anything else.